# Set programmatically image roles

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, image, gallery

I have that in my backoffice :
[image: witout]

and I need that:
[image: with]

This solution does not work for me :

```
  if($key == 1){
        $prod->addImageToMediaGallery($imgPath, array('image', 'small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
    }else{
        $prod->addImageToMediaGallery($imgPath, null, false, false);
    }
    $prod->save();
```

How can I do ?

Thank you

EDIT :
my new implementation, but it is not working :

```
if(!$productFactory) $productFactory=$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$product=$productFactory->create()->load($id_product_for_image);
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($tmpName, $is_cover ? array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image') : array(), false, false);
```

I think it is connected to this problem : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34658

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Following code to overcome this

```
/** \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product */
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
foreach ($totalImages as $index => $path) {
   $type = [];
   if ($index == 0) {
       $type = ['image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'];
   }
   $product->addImageToMediaGallery(
             $path,
             $type,
             false,
             false
   );
}
```

Comment: sorry, I know this is a relevant and obvious way to do it but it doesn't work for me. The images remain as if without a role in both cases. It may depend on the magento version.

Comment: my magento version is 2.4.3-p1. You can see my personnal implementation on the first post. But I have tested it on  Magento ver. 2.3.7-p2 and it is working !!